# What's wrong with my TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I've just installed MacTeX-2019 on my MacBook.
So I'm using TeXShop 4.27 which comes along.

I'm trying to execute the most basic GNUPLOT example:
http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-basics/

Here is the output I get:

[image]

What could possibly go wrong?

I've tried other examples that work well.
But it looks like there is a specific problem with

\draw plot function

Thanks for your help,

Julien

Comment: is gnuplot installed? is shell-escape enabled?

Comment: @Seamus I don't know: I've just installed MacTeX-2019. How do I check?

Comment: If you read your own link, you will see the prerequisite.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
    \draw[very thin,color=gray] (-0.1,-1.1) grid (3.9,3.9);
    \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
    \draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};
    \draw[color=red] plot ({\x},{\x}) 
        node[right] {$f(x) =x$};
    \draw[color=blue] plot ({\x},{sin(deg(\x))}) 
        node[right] {$f(x) = \sin x$};
    \draw[color=orange] plot ({\x},{0.05*exp(\x)}) 
        node[right] {$f(x) = \frac{1}{20} \mathrm e^x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: ^^^ this does the same but without gnuplot.

Comment: @hpekristiansen Ok, thanks.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Juste making @Seamus comment an answer.

- Gnuplot does not come with MacTeX-2019: so you need to install it.
- Then you have to enable shell-escape as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28586661/2886628